# Using different port numbers on server

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, port, server-side

I am pretty new to socket programming - so this might be a simple question but I'd really like to clarify.

I have a multiple-client to single server program: the individual clients send messages to the server which processes them, and then passes it on the destination i.e. the server is an intermediary.

On the server side, there is one thread for each client which is meant to 'listen' for messages from the clients (which will be placed in a buffer). At the moment all the clients are sending messages to the same port (as far as I can tell).

I am thinking of setting up another thread on which the server will process the messages before transmitting them on. Does it make sense to use another port on the server to send those messages?

I don't mean this to be a discussion, but I don't know what is *common* or more logical to do - any advice?

On the client-side, I am planning for it to have one thread for sending messages to the server, and another thread for receiving. Please let me know if any other information is required!

**edit**

At the moment it is a 1-server-to-multiple(tens now, hundreds later)-client program - I seem to have problems with the client receiving messages from my server (I am troubleshooting so I thought that using the same ports might be the problem), but I will try it with the same ports again and see. I thought it might be a matter of the *receiving* port being too busy to *send* messages as well.

Comment: I'm assuming the same server sends and receives messages to the client(s), if so then you would likely use the same port. I can't see why not. Otherwise with multiple servers it might be wise to use two ports. Maybe for troubleshooting reasons later on.

Comment: What OS are you using? On Linux there is `select` system call, which can be used to get rid of threads almost completely. The server cycle will look like this: `select` gives you information about descriptors(sockets), that are ready to give you data. You loop over these sockets and process data (accept connections/generate responses), then you repeat this again.

Comment: What is the exact intention of the program ? Client-server programs can range from 1client-1server to 1000clients-100servers, each with different architectures for different requirements.

Comment: As for the port numbers, you need only one listening socket to accept connections. Using another port to reply to clients doesn't make any sense, because when you establish connection with sockets, you then have a full-duplex channel, so you can receive messages from it and send it over the same socket. You don't really want to open multiple connections between your server and a single client.

Comment: For a few hundred clients non-blocking IO with select will be good enough (on Linux). You may want to have multiple processes / threads on the server to handle the messages depending on how long processing a message takes and how long a client can wait.

Comment: BTW you should check if your receiving port is non-blocking (or asynchronous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the moment all the clients are sending messages to the same port (as far as I can tell).

What do you mean 'as far as I can tell'? You must know whether you are opening more than one port at the server.

> Does it make sense to use another port on the server to send those messages?

No it doesn't. If you're using TCP, send the messages back down the same socket. If you're using UDP you don't need more than one UDP socket, and it simplifies the client and the application protocol if replies come from the same ip:port the request was sent from.

Comment: EJP means here that TCP connection is bidirectional and sends and receives data simultaneously. As server can accept many connections on a single port, there almost never is a need to keep more ports open.

Comment: @Basilevs Don't presume to tell people what I mean. I can do my own explaining, when necessary, and in fact what I *really* meant here was that the question doesn't make sense as posed. The statements you make about TCP are all true but there's no need to hide behind other people when making them.